# ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: System memory 259522560 must be at least 471859200

Tags: java, apache-spark, intellij-idea

So I am new to spark. My versions are: Spark 2.1.2, Scala version 2.11.8 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_131). I am using IntellijIdea 2018 Community on Windows 10 (x64). And whenever I am trying to run a simple word count example I get the following error:

> 18/10/22 01:43:14 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: System memory 259522560 must be at
>   least 471859200. Please increase heap size using the --driver-memory
>   option or spark.driver.memory in Spark configuration.     at
>   org.apache.spark.memory.UnifiedMemoryManager$.getMaxMemory(UnifiedMemoryManager.scala:216)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.memory.UnifiedMemoryManager$.apply(UnifiedMemoryManager.scala:198)
>     at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.create(SparkEnv.scala:330)    at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.createDriverEnv(SparkEnv.scala:174)    at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext.createSparkEnv(SparkContext.scala:257)
>     at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.(SparkContext.scala:432)     at
>   WordCount$.main(WordCount.scala:5)    at WordCount.main(WordCount.scala)

PS: this is the code of the wordcounter that use as an example:

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf,SparkContext}
object WordCount {
def main(args: Array[String]) {
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("mySpark").setMaster("local")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val rdd = sc.textFile(args(0))
val wordcount = rdd.flatMap(_.split("\t") ).map((_, 1))
  .reduceByKey(_ + _)
for (arg <- wordcount.collect())
  print(arg + " ")
println()
//    wordcount.saveAsTextFile(args(1))
//    wordcount.saveAsTextFile("myFile")
sc.stop()
}
}
```

So my question is how to get rid of this error. I have searched for the solution and tried installing different versions of Spark and JDK and Hadoop, but it didn't help. I don't know where may be the problem.

Comment: Please try solution from similar thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35745052/apache-spark-memory-exception-error-intellij-settings

Answer (score 4):

Go to settings - run/debug configurations -> and for VM options put

-Xms128m -Xms512m -XX:MaxPermSize=300m -ea

Answer (score 4):

If you are in IntelliJ you may struggle a lot, What I did and it worked is that I have initialized SparkContext before SparkSession by doing

1. `val conf:SparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("name").setMaster("local")
   .set("spark.testing.memory", "2147480000")`
2. `val sc:SparkContext = new SparkContext(conf)`

There is maybe a better solution, because here I actually don't need to initialise SparkContext since it is implicitly done by initialising SparkSession.